# Can't access Cloud9 on port 8081 on Google cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, firewall, iptables, cloud9-ide, cloud9

I can't access Cloud9 on port 8081 running on Google cloud platform.

I am sure the application is running on that port and applications on the same machine on other ports (e.g. `http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:3000`) are accessible correctly, so this doesn't seem to be an issue with the `iptables` settings.

I receive no response from the server `http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8081/`.

Google Cloud Platform configuration:

> Allowed protocols and ports include tcp:8000-8089
>
> IP Address set up as static and external

Command used to run Cloud9:

```
node server.js -w /home/workspace -l 0.0.0.0 -p 8081 -a username:password
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I have accidentally added some **Target tags** in the Google cloud firewall settings (`Networking > Firewall rules`).

Removing those tags solved my problem, I just use the default **Apply to all targets** setting.